# Change position of x-axis values in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart library, I created a simple chart example:

[image]

and I want to change to position of value X:

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);

    BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setDescription("My Chart");
    chart.animateXY(0, 5000);
    chart.invalidate();
}

private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

    ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(98.000f, 0); // Jan
    valueSet1.add(v1e1);
    BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(95.000f, 1); // Feb
    valueSet1.add(v1e2);
    BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(102.000f, 2); // Mar
    valueSet1.add(v1e3);
    BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(101.000f, 3); // Apr
    valueSet1.add(v1e4);
    BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(99.000f, 4); // May
    valueSet1.add(v1e5);
    BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(97.000f, 5); // Jun
    valueSet1.add(v1e6);


    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
    barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
    return dataSets;
}

private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
    ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
    xAxis.add("Tue");
    xAxis.add("Web");
    xAxis.add("Thu");
    xAxis.add("Fri");
    xAxis.add("Sat");
    xAxis.add("Sun");
    return xAxis;
}
}
```

please help me, thanks so much!

Comment: are you missing some images??

Comment: Yes, I'm. But, I can't add photos to this post. You can see at here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/boplv.png                                                                      https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM6DL.png

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
       xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM)` to set the x-axis position.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from you query , you want to move your X-cordinates on bottom of the graph, please correct me if I am wrong.

If that is so then try [GraphView - com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView).

This is how I am using it.

[image]

Comment: exactly as you say you do, your understanding exactly like me. But what I need is mpandroidchart. Anyway thank you very much